# Is it undefined behavior to pass-by-reference uninitialized variable?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, undefined-behavior

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int &x) {
    x = 5;
}

int main() {
    int x;
    f(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Does this code invoke undefined behavior in C++? g++ compiles it without any warnings and the code prints out `5` (as expected?).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior in this code.  It would be undefined to **use** an uninitialized variable before it has been assigned a value, but it is well-defined to pass around a reference and to perform an assignment via a reference.

Comment: The key is that an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an uninitialized value results in UB.

Comment: There isn't, which is why there's no UB :-) (Well, there *are* rvalues, of course, such as `5`, `0`, and the result of rvalue-to-lvalue conversion of `x` in the `cout` line.) But I was just trying to give a more precise definition of what you mean by "use".

Answer (score 6):

Undefined behaviour occurs when an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, with a few exceptions (see §8.5/12 of the C++14 standard).

In this case, the value of `x` isn't used until after `x` has been assigned to, so this code is fine. The value of `x` is not accessed in order to bind a reference to it. (However, beware: an `int` can also be bound to a `const double&`, in which case the value *would* be accessed, and a new temporary `double` object would be created from that value.)

Answer (score 2):

No, this does not invoke undefined behavior and the expected print value is 5.
Since you declared your function as `void f(int& x)` the `int&` is a reference type and changes the value of the variable it is bound to and does not copy it.

Be aware of what is a real example of undefined behavior with references:

```
int& f() {
    int x = 5;
    return x; //return a reference of a variable that will not exist
    //after f finished
} 

int main() {
    std::cout << f() << std::endl; //undefined behavior 
}
```

This is undefined behavior since references do not take responsibility of keeping allocated data valid that they refer to, the reference just changes and reads values if they are valid. So after `f()` is finished the reference is going to point to invalid memory.