# Is passing the uninitialized variable to function considered UB in C++?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, return-value-optimization, sanitizer

Recently I was writing my raytracer project and made some bugs in it. I have a function:

```cpp
double Length(const Vector& v) {
    return std::sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2]);
}
```

and then I had a typo in this statement:

```cpp
Vector normal = Length(normal) < eps ? intersection.GetNormal() : baricentric.GetNormal();
```

So when `normal` passed to function it is declared but not defined (the name was not present in other scope, but this). The program ran incorrectly and I had to debug it with gdb before the bug was found.

I expect that it should be UB, but when I built my project with clang, using this flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_ASAN "-g -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all"
    CACHE STRING "Compiler flags in asan build"
    FORCE)
```

I did not get Compiler Error or even Runtime Error during program run.

So is it UB? Should USAN catch this kind of bugs? I have a hypothesis that the problem may be in some compiler optimizations,( RVO e.g ), so if I would compile program with -O0 will it turn off all optimization or I need another flag?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."*

Comment: reading from unitialized variables UB no matter how convoluted the path to that read is. Writing to it is fine (even through references)

Comment: Actually passing by reference is not UB but if you were to evaluate the parameter inside the function then it would be UB. See the dupe: [Is it undefined behavior to pass-by-reference uninitialized variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306345/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-pass-by-reference-uninitialized-variable))

Comment: Also [Calling function with variable that is being initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643920/calling-function-with-variable-that-is-being-initialized)